# In Kali running on PD for Mac, which shortcut is the copy and paste key?

Tags: mac, kali-linux, parallels

I've tried <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> ,  <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> , <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> , but they don't work. I've been using the right mouse button for times. How can I operate correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried kill & yank?
 <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>K</kbd>  and  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Y</kbd> 
idk Kali, so just a guess. Kill is a cut rather than copy, but you can yank it back to the same place if you need.

It's from Emacs & used by many 'nix' flavours. It actually works on the Mac too - https://www.howtogeek.com/293850/how-to-use-macos-built-in-kill-and-yank-as-an-alternative-cut-and-paste/

Comment: No,  ⌃K didn' work. But when I switch the Desktop from GNOME to XFCE,  ⌃⇧C work.